# how to post to google stream from server side code in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, rest, google-plus

In my website, when a google user sign up's with a google account i need to post a interactive post or share a post to his google + stream from my server side code.

through authentication process i will get the tokens and other required parameters... but i am unable to find the google REST endpoint to post to google+ stream.

I have no idea how to do that from server side code... all that was have been able to see on Developer.google.com was posting to code via javascript.. but i don't want that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way for you to post to a user's stream from the server. All posting activity must be specifically triggered by the user, and this is only done via the client-side actions. Your asp.net can, of course, dynamically generate a page with the javascript, but the user still must take an action to do so.

You may also want to look into [app activities](https://developers.google.com/+/web/app-activities/), which let you post something to the user's profile, but not directly to their stream.